# Problem getting parent in a MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a question in one column, a list of answers in another. I'm using contentEditable to be able to make changes to the text and using a mutationObserver to detect the changes so I can flag that row as edited.  My problem is, if I erase all the text in one spot, it's not retrieving the parent row (TR tag).  It's hard to explain, easier to see in action. If you click on one of the answers to edit it, delete each character and in the console it'll show it's grabbing the parent row. But as soon as you delete the last character of that particular text, it fails to retrieve the parent properly.  I'm not entirely sure why.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    parentRow = $(mutations[0].target).parent().closest('tr');
    $(parentRow).attr('data-edit', 1);
    console.log(parent)
  });

  config = {
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
  };
  $('[contenteditable]').each(function(i, e) {
    observer.observe($(this)[0], config);
  });
});
```

```css
table,
table td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" id="tblQuestions">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%">Actions</th>
      <th width="60%">Question</th>
      <th width="">Answers</th>
      <th width="5%">Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="29" data-edit="0">
      <td>
        <button>X</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div contenteditable="true">Do you like the T-rex? </div>
      </td>
      <td><button>&plus;</button>
        <ol>
          <li data-id="122" contenteditable="true">Yes</li>
          <li data-id="147" contenteditable="true">No</li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @user4642212 that was a copying error, he has it correct in the fiddle that I copied to a snippet.

Comment: `$(this)[0]` can be just `this`.